# Manual enumeration of equation without using the commmand 'tag'

Tags: numbering, alignment

I need to enumerate some lines and some equation of a document, and since I need ome freedom editing the layout I want to put manually some numbers at the end of a line.
I've found a solution when the line is not centered, that is using 
text or equation `\qquad\hspace*{\fill} number` or anything else at the end of the line.
Now, clearly if I use:

```
\begin{center} text \end{center}\qquad\hspace*{\fill} number
```

The text will not be centered. How can I obtain the same result but with text centered and number on the right?

Comment: please provide a mwe (minimal working example, a small but complete document) by which you show your attempt. `tag` is defined for manual numerating equations, why you not like to use it and invent own solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? (I'm sure that there is other more professional option)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
text here\\
\hfill{}text here\hfill\llap{(1)}\\
text here
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `equation`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newenvironment{numberedtext}[1]
 {\begin{equation}\tag{#1}\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}\centering}
 {\end{minipage}\end{equation}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\begin{numberedtext}{1}
some text to be centered
\end{numberedtext}
\lipsum*[4]
\begin{numberedtext}{42}
some other text
\end{numberedtext}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

In order to ensure there is space for the number, the width of the minipage is less than the textwidth.

[image]